# Showing flash above content

Tags: html, css, flash, z-order

I have a page with a tutorial (http://www.poromenos.org/tutorials/bittorrent/download), but the site layout obscures the flash player, which is too wide. Is there a way to show the flash above the content through the z-order (or something else, lightbox-y)?

Answer (score 1):

You could place IFrame with player- it would be above all page content

Answer (score 1):

I would definitely suggest using a lightbox instead. If you just tried to push it up in the z-index you'll cover navigation which is going to cause you usability issues. I'm a big fan of [FancyBox](http://fancy.klade.lv/) - it's pretty quick-n-easy and it uses jQuery which you are already using. Looking at the download page you can see the details on Inline Content with a Flash example.

Comment: I would prefer placing it over navigation for now, mainly because I don't want to include the js dependencies in every page just for this one. I tried to do z-index: 0 but it didn't work in Opera/IE, while Firefox always shows it on top...

Comment: Oh wait, I didn't notice it was using jQuery. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

Lightbox is a good way. Or you can just add link to the video or optimize player's size.